# Protobuf equivalent of JsonHttpClient?

Tags: servicestack, protobuf-net

is there an equivalent of the new (-ish) JsonHttpClient that uses protobuf-net instead of JSON ? I realize that the old-style ProtobufServiceClient exists, but I'd like to replace it with something that uses HttpClient, instead of the old HttpWebRequest.

If such a client does not exist, how hard would it be to write one ? Should I just copy/paste JsonHttpClient.cs and change a few things, or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't another ServiceClient for ProtoBuf other than [ProtobufServiceClient](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#httpwebrequest-service-clients). The easiest approach would be to take a copy of [JsonHttpClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.HttpClient/JsonHttpClient.cs) and modify it to use ProtoBuf, but `JsonHttpClient` wasn't designed to support multiple Content Types so it's not going to be as straight-forward as implementing a new ServiceClient.